# Confusion regarding scope of pointer and the data it points to

Tags: c++, pointers, scope

Consider the following simple c++ code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<int> aPtr;

void simpleFunc()
{
    int aInt=10;
    aPtr = std::make_unique<int>(aInt);
}
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    simpleFunc();
    
    std::cout<<"\nPrint: "<< *aPtr;
    return 0;
}
```

The scope of aPtr is global while that of `aInt` is local to `simpleFunc()`. The first question is can I try to access the local variable outside its scope using a pointer that is still in scope?
I tried printing the value and it prints 10 as expected but I am not sure if this is just by chance or if the value 10 is actually valid.

The second question is, is there a way to check if a memory location is "free" or in used currently

Comment: `std::make_unique<int>(aInt)` copies `aInt` and stores that value in the integer object that `aPtr` points to.

Comment: Why would you even want to know where a value is stored? And in general don't use global variables. Create your unique_ptr instance in main and pass a reference to the std::unique_ptr (or a non-owning int*) to simpleFunc. And you can't check if a memory location is "free" if the make_unique succeeded there was enough memory to allocate an int somewhere if it failed you ran out of memory. See [std::make_unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) and then look for std::bad_alloc

Comment: The smart "pointers" aren't really pointers, they are just regular objects. And `make_unique` creates new objects, not pointers to existing objects..

Comment: @PepijnKramer I didn't mean to use global variables in my actual code, it was just for the purpose of this question. This question was asked to clear some confusion about pointer and variable scope.

Comment: A std::unique_ptr is an object and not a pointer. Thus it also follows the normal rules for object lifetime. Its destructor will be called when it goes out of scope (and for a global variable that is somewhere after main exits). In the unique_ptr's destructor the memory will be freed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first question is can I try to access the local variable outside its scope using a pointer that is still in scope?

No, you can't. Local variables are allocated on the stack and as such the memory that they occupy is no longer available for their use once the variable goes out of scope.

However, this isn't what you're code is doing anyways:

> ```
> std::unique_ptr<int> aPtr;
>
> void simpleFunc()
> {
>     int aInt=10;
>     aPtr = std::make_unique<int>(aInt);
> }
> ```

This creates a `new int` and stores the value of `aInt` in it. So `aPtr` does not point to the local `aInt`. It points to a new `int`, whose value was initialized with `10`. It would be safe to access the value of `aPtr` globally, as it does not point to that local variable.

> The second question is, is there a way to check if a memory location is "free" or in used currently

This question needs more context. Generally speaking, no. The idiom here is to set pointers to `nullptr` after you free them (and initialize them to `nullptr` when you declare them), and then check if they're equal to `nullptr` later when you need to. This would be typical:

```
    // init to null so we know it points nowhere
    int *aPtr = nullptr;

    // example of testing for null
    if (!aPtr) { /* aPtr is null */ }

    // create an int, aPtr will no longer be null
    aPtr = new int;

    // when you free it, set it to null immediately 
    delete aPtr;
    aPtr = nullptr;

    // so now you know that aPtr is either a valid pointer, or it is null.
    // (except for that moment between delete and =nullptr, where it is garbage)
```

For a `unique_ptr`, which handles all of the above for you, you can use its built-in `operator bool` to check if it contains a pointer or not, e.g.:

```
if (!aPtr) {
    // then aPtr is null (e.g. uninitialized or reset() was called to free)
}
```

Also, if you are using `std::shared_ptr`, and you have an `std::weak_ptr` to the same object, the `weak_ptr` will let you know when the shared pointer is released.

Comment: I would say that if you feel the need to check if your pointers have been deleted or not then there's something wrong with your code. Most of the time, if you must delete something, then you should do it in a destructor, that way there can be no question about whether a pointer has been deleted or not. If you can still access it then it has not been deleted.

Comment: @john "Something wrong with your code" is a bit harsh and I don't think this is a good rule of thumb. I don't think it's fair to make new programmers believe that checking if pointers are null = their code is broken. The best sign that there's something wrong with your code is that there's something wrong with your code. There are plenty of reasonable situations where you might want to check if a pointer is null. There are also plenty of ways to avoid doing that if you don't find it palatable. The choice of one or the other just comes down to whatever is the best tool for the job at hand.

Comment: I was specifically talking about checking for deleted pointers. Obviously there are many cases where you need to check for a null pointer and there's nothing wrong with that.